# Is there a way to connect to a simple TCP socket in React Native?

Tags: react-native, sockets, networking

I have created a Java server that uses ServerSocket, and now I am trying to create a simple application in React Native to interface with it. How can I connect to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to socket by :

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
```

downloading this `socket.io-client`.

Now in your constructor or componentDidMountyou can do this:

```
this.socket = io.connect(url, {transports: ['websocket']});
```

Hope it helps.